# How to use google map api key in my Joomla 1.5 article

Tags: google-maps, joomla1.5

I am using Joomla 1.5 . I have generated a google map api key . How to use this key in Joomla article.

Answer (score 0):

The first result on google turned up:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/signup.html

Answer (score 0):

Lucky for you the work has already been done for you. Use the [Google Maps](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/maps-a-weather/maps-a-locations/maps/1147) plugin and you can generate maps in your content easily.